# What is the purpose of the "include ignored resources" checkbox in VCS in IntellJ IDEA?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, version-control

In IntelliJ IDEA, when Version Control integration is turned on for the first time (SVN in my case), and the user decides to import his project into VCS, then after choosing the repository, you get to choose the directory to import. As a standard, the `include ignored resources` checkbox is always activated and must be deactivated manually. This puzzles me: After spending lots of time de-tangling projects partially disfigured by having files in VCS that should have been ignored, and setting up ignore lists, I just can't see a way this option would be useful, and even if it was, why it would be activated as a standard. What am I missing here? Isn't it "standard" *not* to include ignored resources when importing?

The documentation doesn't give any hints regarding this.

I'd just like to know whether there is an aspect of VCS in general or SVN in this case, that I'm missing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is specific to the Subversion Version Control Integration. It indeed seems a little unnecessary to activate the option by default. Perhaps you want to file a bug report about it?

Comment: Did so, let's see what will happen.

Comment: Great! Here is [the bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148689) for any that are interested.